# Camera.PreviewCallback no callback

Tags: callback, camera

(version:android 4.1) I want add some effect when the camera start preview. but is same the onPreviewFrame  function 
did not called. I know if use setdisplaypreview() method the onPreviewFrame will be called.
but there's no way for me to add effect for preview.

So please tell me how to make it works. Thanks for your help.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
    //SurfaceView surfaceview = new SurfaceView(this);
    mHolder = mSurface.getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
     initCamera();
}

void openDevice() {
    if (mCamera == null) {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
    }
}

private void initCamera()  {
    openDevice();
    Camera.Parameters parameter = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameter.setPictureSize(PREVIEW_WIDTH, PREVIEW_HEIGHT);
    parameter.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameter);
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
}

private void drawBitmap(Bitmap map) {

    Canvas canvas = mHolder.lockCanvas();
    if (null != canvas) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        if (null != canvas) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(map, null, mDestRect, paint);
            mSurface.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
        mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}
    @Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    if (holder.getSurface() == null) {
        return;
    }
    mHolder = holder;
    if (mCamera == null) {
        return;
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if( null != mCamera){

        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(mPreviewCallBack);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
}
    Camera.PreviewCallback mPreviewCallBack = new Camera.PreviewCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        int format = camera.getParameters().getPreviewFormat();
        Size s = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();

        Log.e(TAG, "xxxxxxxxxx");
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            byteStream.write(data);
            //TODO I have add some effect here.

            mOutBitmap
                    .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteStream);
            byteStream.close();
                           //Draw the preview image.
            drawBitmap(mOutBitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In initCamera() & onSurfaceCreated() method, use the below code and see the output :-

```
byte[] mVideoSource;

public void initCamera(){
    openDevice();
    Camera.Parameters parameter = mCamera.getParameters();

    PixelFormat lPixelFormat = new PixelFormat();
    PixelFormat.getPixelFormatInfo(parameter.getPreviewFormat(), lPixelFormat);
    int lSourceSize = PREVIEW_WIDTH * PREVIEW_HEIGHT * lPixelFormat.bitsPerPixel / 8;
    mVideoSource = new byte[lSourceSize];

    parameter.setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.YCbCr_420_SP);
    parameter.setPictureSize(PREVIEW_WIDTH, PREVIEW_HEIGHT);
    parameter.setPreviewSize(PREVIEW_WIDTH, PREVIEW_HEIGHT);

    mCamera.setParameters(parameter);
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mVideoSource);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if( null != mCamera){
    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
    mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mVideoSource);
    mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(previewCallback);
    mCamera.startPreview();
}
```